# EOFError in converting string to list

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle, eoferror

I have a code which is running on 2 hosts. They are processing some photos. When host1 receives a message, it will send some of its photos to host2 for processing. It will also send a list to host2 (it will convert it to string and then it will send it).

```
import pickle
import time, threading

host = commands.getoutput("hostname -I")
port = 5005
i = 0
backlog = 5
BUFSIZE = 4096
queueList = []
start = []
end = []
l = threading.Lock()

def read_udp(s):
    data,addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
    global start
    if data.startswith('10.0.0'):
        print("received message:", data)
        data_split = data.split(" ")
        address = data_split[0]
        num = int(data_split[1])
        ipToTransfer = address
        l.acquire()
        transferList = queueList[-num:]
        del queueList[-num:]
        transferStart = start[-num:]
        del start[-num:]
        l.release()
        msg = pickle.dumps(transferStart)
        #udp_send('New Transfer', ipToTransfer)
        udp_send(msg, ipToTransfer)
        send_file(ipToTransfer, transferList) 
    else:
        recvStart = pickle.loads(data)
        print("start before add::: ", start)
        print("received::: ", recvStart)
        l.acquire()
        start = start + recvStart
        l.release()
        print("start after add::: ", start)

def udp_send(s, ip):
    UDP_IP = ip
    if(type(s) == str):
        MESSAGE = s
    else:
        MESSAGE = pickle.dumps(s)   
    #print(MESSAGE)
    print ("UDP target IP & port:", UDP_IP, port)
    print ("message:", MESSAGE)
    sock3 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
    sock3.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, port))

class Receiver:
    ''' Buffer binary data from socket conn '''
    def __init__(self, conn):
        self.conn = conn
        self.buff = bytearray()

    def get(self, size):
        ''' Get size bytes from the buffer, reading
            from conn when necessary 
        '''
        while len(self.buff) < size:
            data = self.conn.recv(BUFSIZE)
            if not data:
                break
            self.buff.extend(data)
        # Extract the desired bytes
        result = self.buff[:size]
        # and remove them from the buffer
        del self.buff[:size]
        return bytes(result)

    def save(self, fname):
        ''' Save the remaining bytes to file fname '''
        with open(fname, 'wb') as f:
            if self.buff:
                f.write(bytes(self.buff))
            while True:
                data = self.conn.recv(BUFSIZE)
                if not data:
                    break
                f.write(data)

def send(sock2, data2):
    while data2:
        sent = sock2.send(data2)
        data2 = data2[sent:]

def send_file(ipToTransfer, transferList):
    while transferList:
        fname = transferList.pop(0)
        print("transferring:", fname)
        with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
            sock2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            try:
                sock2.connect((ipToTransfer, 5005))
            except socket.error as err:
                print(err, ipToTransfer, 5005)
                sock2.close()
                return

            # Send the file name length & the filename itself in one packet
            send(sock2, pack('B', len(fname)) + fname.encode())
            while True:
                data2 = f.read(BUFSIZE)
                if not data2:
                    break
                send(sock2, data2)

        sock2.close()
```

When host2 receives this string, it will convert it to list again, but I receive an EOFError in this part. My cmd doesn't have the copy capability, so I upload the photo from this error:

[image]

What's wrong?

Comment: where is send_file and udp_send defined?

Comment: You should add pickle as a tag

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @eagle33322 I added them

Comment: queueList  is empty when assigned to transferList?

Comment: @eagle33322 No, it has plenty of images inside.

Comment: you del the reference to what transferstart is looking at so the pointer is gone when pickle is looking for it, not a real copy

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: In python2.7, `EOFError` is raised when the data passed in to `pickle.loads()` is empty. As a first step, could you print the value of `data` before passing it to `recvStart = pickle.loads(data)` and just check for content?

Answer (score 0):

you delete the pointer to what is being pickled

```
        transferStart = start[-num:]
        del start[-num:]
        l.release()
        msg = pickle.dumps(transferStart)
```

If you are trying to remove elements from a list that is not the way to do it. Consider popping or reassigning into another list that does not have that element, etc.

Comment: you can slice or find multiple indices if they are not contiguous

Comment: I have not been successful yet, I will accept as soon as I succeed. It was working until I increased the number of images.